# How to resize /home partition to solve "No space left on device"?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, storage

When I tried to install some python packages with pip, I got `[Errno 28] No space left on device`. Can I add some free space from `sdb` to `/home`(or `/`)?

```
>> df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4       773G  733G     0 100% /home
/dev/sdb1       7.3T  2.4T  4.5T  35% /home/data_hdd
```

```
>> lsblk
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 143.1G  0 part /home/data_hdd
├─sda2   8:2    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3   8:3    0   977M  0 part /boot
└─sda4   8:4    0 785.6G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   7.3T  0 part /home/data_hdd
```

```
>> lsblk -o +fstype
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0 143.1G  0 part /home/data_hdd                 ext4
├─sda2   8:2    0   1.9G  0 part [SWAP]                         swap
├─sda3   8:3    0   977M  0 part /boot                          ext4
└─sda4   8:4    0 785.6G  0 part /home                          ext4
sdb      8:16   0   7.3T  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0   7.3T  0 part /home/data_hdd                 ext4
```

One solution according to my knowledge may be using lvm to create a logical volume containing sda and sdb and reinstall the system on it. But it's my group's server, so erasing disks and reinstalling is the last choice.

Comment: Your system doesn't use LVM, so there's that. 773GB of data sounds like a lot, I'm sure you can delete something to free up space.

Comment: What are the file systems on the involved partitions?

Comment: If `sda` and `sdb` are physical disks, you cannot move free space from one to the other. But if they are virtual disks in a VM or hardware RAID, or LUNs in a SAN, then it might be possible to resize them. Your `lsblk` says `sda1` and `sdb1` are both mounted at `/home/data_hdd` and have different capacities, which is strange (normally impossible). Please show the output of `lsblk -o +fstype`. Is this some sort of a VPS or container?

Comment: @telcoM "`sda1` and `sdb1` are both mounted at `/home/data_hdd`" confused me too. Also, there is no partition for `/`.  I'm not the one who builds and set up this server. So, I'm trying to find a way to solve my problem without reinstalling os. But after a day's searching, maybe backup data, setup btrfs or ext4 over lvm and reinstall the system is the only way.

Comment: The odd display of `sda1` and `sdb1`, and the fact that the root filesystem is not mentioned make me think this might be some sort of a Virtual Private Server or a container. If so, then there might be ways to address the disk space issue through the VPS/container management interface, whatever it is.

Comment: Instead of deleting files, try moving them to a directory on /home/data_hdd/.  and optionally create symlinks from the original location to their new location.   this would probably work best if you could find a large directory with a few tens or hundreds of GB in it and move-and-symlink the entire directory.